# How to use setWakeMode method in media player android?

Tags: android-mediaplayer

I am using media player for phone ringing,i want to screen on when phone is ringing please help me

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

To get the ringing event :

```
private PhoneStateListener  phoneStateListener  = new PhoneStateListener() {
                                                        @Override
                                                        public void onCallStateChanged(int state, String incomingNumber) {

                                                            switch (state) {
                                                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_RINGING:
                                                                    break;
                                                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_OFFHOOK:
                                                                    break;
                                                                case TelephonyManager.CALL_STATE_IDLE:
                                                                    break;
                                                            }
                                                        }
                                                    };
```

Set the observer :

```
    try {
            TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
            telephonyManager.listen(phoneStateListener, PhoneStateListener.LISTEN_CALL_STATE);
        }
        catch (SecurityException e) {
            // don't have READ_PHONE_STATE
        }
```

And to keep your screen on

solution 1 :

```
getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

solution 2 :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>

yourwakelock = getContext().getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE).newWakeLock(PowerManager.SCREEN_BRIGHT_WAKE_LOCK, getClass().getName());
```

that's all for now